# Mysql query in Database

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-5, phpmyadmin

How to get all the tables from database with all values in tables using single query..
I tried using

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$arrayCount = 0
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$tableNames[$arrayCount] = $row[0];
$arrayCount++; //only do this to make sure it starts at index 0
}
foreach ($tableNames as &$name {
$query = "INSERT INTO metadata (table_name) VALUES ('".$name."')";
mysql_query($query);
}
```

but it gives me only tables name

Comment: Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish, here?

Comment: this question could be moved to stackoverflow because this is an PHP...

Answer (score 1):

Use the information_schema.columns table

i.e.

select table_name,column_name from information_schema.columns